# Trato de hacer una calculadora

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora que tenga overloaded methods y methods with arguments, pero ya de inicio me da lineas rojas en partes del codigo. No quiero usar un even handler button directamente para cada operaciona aritmetica porque entonces no podria hacer overloading methods. El problema principal que tengo ahora es enlazar el resultado de la suma con la etiqueta de XAML. He probado estas dos variantes en relacion con la variable de resultado sum dentro de DoSomeMath method y sigue dando lineas rojas:

```
sum= operation.Text;

 DoSomeMath = operation.Text;

operation es el nombre de la etiqueta que dara resultado en XAML, la parte visible.

  Codigoen C#

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label3.Text = Calculator.calculator.DoSomeMath(operation.Text);
        }

    }

    namespace Calculator
    {
        class calculator
        {

            public static int DoSomeMath(int num1, int num2)
            {

                int sum = num1 + num2;

                return sum;


            }

          
        }
```

Comment: Procura especificar cuál es el problema en específico que estás teniendo, desde la pregunta. "No me funciona" no nos da un indicio rápido del problema en particular. Además, el editor que estás utilizando probablemente te indica el significado de esas líneas rojas. ¿Qué mensaje te arroja? Lee [ask].

Comment: esto es c#... pero es asp? winforms? wpf???

Comment: @gbianchi ContentPage forma parte de Xamarin.

Comment: Es windows forms. Gracias

Comment: ok.. entonces empeza por aclarar eso en una etiqueta... ahora, cual es el error? ese codigo no tiene nada malo de por si.... mas si no sabemos que tratas de hacer con el...

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo por que no funciona, no le veo nada, el error es que cuando le doy a la tecla verde para que compile , aparece unas lineas rojas debajo del nombre DoSomeMath que esta en el metodo del Button click y me dice debajo esto : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'num2' of 'calculator.DoSomeMath(int, int)'. Gracias

Comment: El metodo DoSomeMath() tiene dos parametros (num1,num2).  Al llamarlo en tu evento button_click, solo le estas pasando uno. Deberias pasarle dos argumentos ej. Calculator.calculator.DoSomeMath(10,20);. tal vez sea eso

Answer (score 0):

He logrado enlazar las variables con las entry.Text, pero aun sigo teniendo dificultades. Ahora el problema es la conversion de string a int que no sale bien. En este codigo me sale raya roja debajo de calculator.DoSomeMath(num1, num2), y me comenta Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type',
alguna sugerencia?Gracias

namespace Calculator2
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();

```
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

        int num1 = int.Parse(number1.Text);

        int num2 = int.Parse(number2.Text);

        label3.Text = calculator.DoSomeMath(num1, num2);


    }

}

    class calculator
    {

    public static int DoSomeMath(int num1, int num2)
    {

        int sum;
        sum = num1 + num2;
        return sum;
         
     }

}
```

}